# sql query, wildcard, MS SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need my query to pull all DirName's what have the following prefix 'site/test/test/' 
is the correct syntax a '*'

```
SELECT  DirName, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)/1024 as 'SizeKB' 
FROM  alldocs
Where DirName = 'site/test/test/*'
GROUP BY  dirName 
ORDER BY DirName
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use SQL's LIKE clause:

```
SELECT  DirName, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)/1024 as 'SizeKB' 
FROM  alldocs
Where DirName LIKE 'site/test/test/%'
GROUP BY  dirName 
ORDER BY DirName
```

See http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp

Comment: Is there an easy was to include a column total for 'SizeKB'?

Comment: @MG - better if you ask that in another question, to avoid an off-topic discussion using comment space.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL?  If you are, you can use LEFT in something like

```
SELECT  DirName, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)/1024 as 'SizeKB' 
FROM  alldocs
Where LEFT( DirName, LENGTH( 'site/test/test/' ) ) = 'site/test/test/'
GROUP BY  dirName 
ORDER BY DirName
```

Comment: MS sql server doesn't recognize the Length funtion.